# RESTful API - Call and Use Token to Process Order

Tags: php, rest, restful-authentication

I am using Curl in PHP to integrate an API in my site. I will be retrieving the access token and using it to process orders to vendor.

**Retrieve token:**

```
function getToken() {
// authenticate and return $token
$ch = curl_init();

$api_token = $this->config['API'];
$ninjavan_id = $this->config['ID'];
$ninjavan_secret = $this->config['SECRET'];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
  \"client_id\": \"$id\",
  \"client_secret\": \"$secret\",
  \"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\"
}");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Accept: application/json"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($response, true);
$file = 'key.txt';
$token = $json['access_token'];

file_put_contents('./modules/custommodule/key.txt', $token, LOCK_EX);
}
```

I am able to retrieve the token successfully, I have tested the codes. Next will be using the token.

**Process an order:**

```
$file = './modules/custommodule/key.txt';
$retrieved_token = file_get_contents($file);

do {
$retry = false;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_order);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
//curl execution
}");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Accept: application/json",
  "Authorization: Bearer $retrieved_token"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($httpcode === 401) { // unauthorized
    getToken();
    $retry = true;
    }
} 
while ($retry);
curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents('./modules/custommodule/response.txt', $response, LOCK_EX);
file_put_contents('./modules/custommodule/results.txt', $httpcode, LOCK_EX);
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. If you can point out a guidance to refresh token upon expiry, that will be perfect.

Thank you.

Comment: in stead of typing in your json POST field directely, you should use an array with the `json_encode()`function to clear up your code!

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use string variable interpolation:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer {$token}"
));
```

As for handling the refresh token, you should check after each call to the remote API if there was an error because of an expired token, and in that case get a new token and retry the call. This works best if you create some sort of proxy for the remote API, so that this mechanic becomes transparent to the calling code. Here is a very crude example of how you might do this:

```
var $token;

function getToken() {
   // authenticate and return $token as you did before
}

function callAnApiMethod($param1, $param2) {
    global $token;
    do {
        $retry = false;
        $ch = curl_init();
        // ...
        // more setup things, using params of the function, etc.
        // ...
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer {$token}"
        ));

        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        if ($info['http_code'] === 401) { // unauthorized
            $token = getToken();
            $retry = true;
        }
    } while ($retry);
    return json_decode($res);
}
```

Honestly, I would never again go through the immense trouble of using CURL if I was trying to consume an API, CURL is insanely clunky and verbose. I'd use something like [Guzzle](https://hackernoon.com/creating-rest-api-in-php-using-guzzle-d6a890499b02).

---

Also, as @Odyssey1111 pointed out, you can use array notation to represent your JSON and then use json_encode to get a string:

```
$payload = [
    'field' => 'value',
    'arrayField' => [
         'subfield' => 'subfieldValue',
    ]
];
$jsonStr = json_encode($payload);
```

This makes your code much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: The for access token and orders are pointing to different URLs. I am looking for a way to merge these 2 process into one php file.

Comment: You can, you just have to use functions... basically you put your *retrieve token* code in the `getToken` function, but just make sure instead of `echo $token` you `return $token`.

Comment: Thank you for your tips, I will get it on with functions as proposed. Let me try tonight and update you on the result. Thanks!

Comment: Can I just add that getToken() will generate multiple token upon code execution? Is it possible to cache $token? Because I do not think the token will expire as I am generating different tokens per execution.

Comment: Yes! This code I posted naturally caches $token for a single script execution, as it's a global variable (though to cache it across multiple runs you'd need to persist it somewhere else).

Comment: Not sure what you meant by having getToken returning multiple tokens, why would you want that? You can reuse the same token multiple times until it expires.

Comment: Hello @Ezequiel Muns, I have updated the codes. I have added  curl_close($ch); after the do-while loop. For caching of token, I have used a file to insert the token. Appreciate if you can are able to check the changes as I am unsure if the conditions set is on point. Can I check if the $retry=false and $retry=true is a way you break the loop?